# Paypal y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

He estado trabajando de forma didáctica con la API de Paypal en modo sandbox, junto con Laravel y todo funciona perfectamente, se realiza la transacción y me redirecciona de nuevo a la página principal de mi sitio después de hacerla. Mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿se pueden configurar más cuentas en el modo sandbox y especificar a la API hacia cuál de estas cuentas quiero hacer la transacción? o por defecto las transacciones se hacen solo a una cuenta en el sandbox.
Mi controlador está de esta forma:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;


class PaypalController extends BaseController{
    private $_api_context;


    public function __construct(){
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'], $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }

    public function postPayment(){
        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $items = array();
        $subtotal = 0;
        $carrito = \Session::get('carrito');
        $currency = 'MXN';

        foreach($carrito as $producto){
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setName($producto->nombre)
            ->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setDescription($producto->descripcion)
            ->setQuantity($producto->can)
            ->setPrice($producto->precio);

            $items[] = $item;
            $subtotal += $producto->can * $producto->precio;
        }

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems($items);

        $total = $subtotal;

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency($currency)
            ->setTotal($total);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Compra cooperativas');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'))
            ->setCancelUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
                echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
                $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
                exit;
            } else {
                die('Ups! Algo salió mal');
            }
        }

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        // add payment ID to session
        \Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            // redirect to paypal
            return \Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        return \Redirect::route('cart-show')
            ->with('message', 'Ups! Error desconocido.');

    }

    public function getPaymentStatus(){
        // Get the payment ID before session clear
        //$payment_id = \Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
        $payment_id = \Input::get('paymentId');

        // clear the session payment ID
        \Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

        $payerId = \Input::get('PayerID');
        $token = \Input::get('token');

        if (empty($payerId) || empty($token)) {
            return \Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('message', 'Hubo un problema al intentar pagar con Paypal');
        }

        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);

        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(\Input::get('PayerID'));

        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);


        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {


            \Session::forget('carrito');

            return \Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('message', 'Compra realizada de forma correcta');
        }
        return \Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('message', 'La compra fue cancelada');

    }    
}
```

Comment: Si estás guardando esa información en base de datos, entonces puedes tener todas las credenciales que quieras, tanto _sandbox_ como _live_, aunque realmente no le veo sentido. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega información sobre porqué quieres tener varias cuentas.

Comment: Si cada producto es ofrecido por un proveedor distinto, ¿cómo le indico a PayPal que le transfiera la cantidad que le corresponde a cada proveedor del total?

Comment: No creo que los usuarios quieran compartirte sus credenciales. Lo que hacen sitios como eBay es cobrar ellos y, cuando paypal libera los fondos, transferir a la cuenta del usuario correspondiente.